# Check if chrome extension inline installation is supported

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension and a JS library to allow installing this extension.

There are a couple of ways to ask a user to install the extension:

1. Inline installation if the site is verified and added to the extension webstore settings.
2. Redirect to chrome webstore otherwise.

Is there a way to check if the inline installation is supported on the site using javascript beforehand?

The only way I found so far is to trigger inline installation and then fallback to redirecting to webstore:

```
chrome.webstore.install(extensionUrl, successCallback, function() {
  redirectToChromeWebstoreExtensionUrl();
});
```

This is not ideal because the redirect will be blocked by chrome since it was not triggered by a user.

What I would like to do is to first check if the site supports inline installation and then choose an appropriate method of installation.

Comment: You can read `<link rel="chrome-webstore-item"` using js and confirm the inline installation is supported or not and as a fallback you can show html+js popup to inform user and offer them link to the webstore.

Comment: What do you mean by "read <link rel="chrome-webstore-item""?

Comment: Read this: https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/inline_installation

Comment: Yes, I did. I still don't understand your point. My library will be adding this link to the DOM in order to install the extension. This link will not just appear in the DOM.